# Keycloak - Limit users access per client/application

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

I've just setup my first Keycloak server to offer SSO between two applications. These are not Java applications, and one is connected with `SAML-2` and the other with `OpenID` Connect.

So in Keycloak I have `Realm-1`, and then `Client-1`(`application1`) and `Client-2`(`application2`) and `user-1` and `user-2`.

Now I want `user-1` to only be allowed access to `Client-1`, and `user-2` to be allowed access to both `Client-1` and `Client-2`. Should be simple enough.

I have tried to read up on Roles and Authorization, but I find the documentation(or maybe just the topic) very confusing. I have been playing around with it with no success. I was expecting an interface to just map a group to a Client, and restrict access to the Clients by adding/removing users from groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SAML:

1. Create a new role in Keycloak.
2. Assign this role to the group.
3. Create new authentication script in Keycloak. Configure which role is allowed upon login (e.g. `user.hasRole(realm.getRole("yourRoleName"))` ).
4. In client setting, under "Authentication Flow overrides" choose the created authentication(from step 3).

If you are using openid, [look at the comment in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305880/how-can-i-restrict-client-access-to-only-one-group-of-users-in-keycloak)

Comment: How to create new authentication script in Keycloak?

Comment: Is there a similar technique for non SAML?

Comment: Instructions are unclear. Please update with an improved answer.

Comment: It's only an option if you set `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled` and `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled`