# Keycloak: Role based client log-in access restriction for users

Tags: security, vue.js, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to achieve fairly simple usecase of role based client application (VueJS multi-page applications) control using the keycloak.

[image: Client role mapping]

As shown in image, I have three different roles and three different clients in single realm.
The arrow in the image represents which role can access which client.

So my main objectives are,

- User with role `Viewer` should only be able to **log-in** to the `Viewer Application`. If the same user tries to access the `Operator Application` or `Admin application` then keycloak should simply deny this user from doing so.
- The same rules should follow for users with `Admin` and `Operator` role. Users of `Admin` role should be able to **log-in** to any of these application by keycloak.

To achieve this usecase I tried following ways,

- First by appropriate role mapping to users and role creation in the clients. In this case, I create realm level roles and then client level roles, then assigned appropriate roles to the users created in the user section.
- Enabling the `Authorization`. In the policies, I removed default policy that grant all users access to the client. And create a `User` policy and `Client` policy to restrict the access to client application
- Also tried with `Group` based authorization policy. In this case, I created a group with client role and then assigned user to these groups. And enabled them from the `Authorization` group policy.

But, unfortunately none of this works. Meaning my user with `Viewer` role can **log-in** to my admin application. Which is just strange.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution proposed by @Stuck is a great start, but it has a significant flaw: When the user has already authenticated, e.g. via the standard flow of another client that did not require the role, the password form flow will never be triggered. Consequently, the user will be logged in via the cookie flow without ever checking for the role.

In other words: If there are other clients (such as the account console) that do not require the role, anyone can **bypass the role check**.

To fix this there needs to be an additional flow layer that includes all authentication executions, that is followed by the authorization step (no matter what authentication flow was used). The final result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: The latest version of the standard Browser Flow is somewhat more complicated because WebAuthn is also in there. It's a pity that Keycloak doesn't let you copy the standard one and drag items into a new sub-flow.

Comment: I implemented this flow, but users still can bypass the role with a set cookie.

Answer (score 28):

You can do this without extensions.

- Copy the desired flow (e.g. the browser flow)
- Create a new sub flow (e.g. for the browser forms) and call it `Access By Role` and select `generic` as type.
- For the new sub flow ensure that `CONDITIONAL` is selected in the flow overview.
- For the new sub flow add execution `Condition - User Role`, make it `REQUIRED` and configure it:

  - alias: admin-role-missing
  - role: admin (or whatever your role is)
  - negate: true
- Add another execution: `Deny Access` and make it `REQUIRED` as well.

The final result should look similar to this:
[image]

This will deny access if the condition "admin-role-missing" is true.

You an also learn more from the docs: [explicitly-deny-allow-access-in-conditional-flows](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#explicitly-deny-allow-access-in-conditional-flows)

Also, don't forget to go to your client and select the flow in the authentication overrides.

Comment: super helpful, thank you

Comment: I have replicated this exact same flow but it doesn't work for me.  The subflow is ignored and access is granted as soon as users authenticate in Username Password Form. Is there something that need to be enabled in Keycloak in order to make the conditional subflows functional? Thanks

Comment: @Metafr did you go to the client and selected the flow in the authentication overrides?

Comment: @Stuck I was looking this solution for days! Thank you very much, works like a charm

Comment: **Warning**: There is a good chance users can bypass the check in your setup if you configure the client like in the screenshot above. See my answer to this question for details (I could not add an image to this comment).

Comment: This works. but lets say I create Authentication Flow for controlling access to a software like Vault with Vault Access Role and bind to Browser Flow. This flow then gets activated for every Authentication even if I doesn't care about the vault access.  Is there some way to resolve this

Comment: Works, thx. However, in case the user doesn't have the specified _Role_ assigned, the response returns code 500 with the body `{"error":"unknown_error"}`. I expected something like 401 unauthorized. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I managed almost the same problem using KeyCloak extension SPI. After the deployment you will have additional configurable "execution" in authentication flows available, named "Validate User Role".

The auth flow then look's like :
[image: example auth flow]

This execution must be placed after the "Username Password Form" (or other form which authenticates user) or the authentication will fail.

The source code is here :
https://github.com/ValentinChirikov/kc_user_role_validate_extension

Comment: The KeyCloak docs i used [Server Developer Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html)

Comment: Nice! This looks like an appropriate solution than checking role at application level.

Comment: But with this solution we have the problem that users can bypass the role check for another client via cookie if already logged in, right?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking to do this in Keycloak version 20, see the screenshot. This is based on answer by @heilerich but for version 20.

**NOTE: Create a new flow instead of duplicating an existing flow as it will not work.**
[image]

Comment: It worked fine for me to duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Finally handled this at the application level as it wasn't working from keycloak end.

After the login, check for the `keycloak` object, inspecting on the same we can find some of the useful properties set during the configuration mentioned in the question above. The overall code looks like below,

```
let appName = 'your_app';
keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(function () {
  // Confirm the role & authentication of the user
  if (keycloak.authenticated && keycloak.tokenParsed.resource_access &&
      keycloak.tokenParsed.resource_access.hasOwnProperty(appName)) {
    // Continue with the app execution...
  } else {
    // Logout user
    keycloak.logout();
  }
}).error(function () {
  keycloak.logout();
});
```

This way I managed to route unauthorized user out of the application.

The solution isn't what's required in the question asked, but it works. Although I think this should be handled at the keycloak level itself.