# Why All LDAP users are able to login into web Application

Tags: authentication, ldap, user-controls, keycloak, fault

We have HPE UOC web application which is integrated with Keycloak for authentication. Further more Keycloak is getting synced via available function *(auto-sync)*.

Apparently this web app don't have any functionality to restrict the all users of LDAP getting logged in. like (*unable/disable user*)

Every user on LDAP can successfully login into web app. we want to restrict the user which don't use this web app. so that only authorized (we granted access to) users can login.

Is there any way to create some policy on Keycloak level so that we can achieve this functionality ? or some other way to restrict all user from LDAP ?

Comment: You are using OIDC protocol, which is designed for authentication (not authorization). But you (may) have a lot of user details (e. g. user roles, email,..) in the generated access token, which app can use for authorization. But that's an app responsibility. Some users are scripting authorization logic with scripted mappers, but I would say that's very legacy approach. You may also add authorization proxy in front of your app.

Comment: Hi @JanGaraj thank you for response. Authorization is taken care by App and its is working fine. lets assume this scenario, we have not assigned any role to User A, but User a is available on LDAP. so when User A tried to login the App, User A will be logged in successfully but cannot see any page because no role is assigned. so is there any way to prevent that user on Keycloak level ?

Comment: Keycloak (OIDC) is `Identity Provider` (IDP) - it provides identity primarily, not authorization. Your app should have some nice "Not Authorize" page instead of "user can't see any page". All other approaches violates "IDP provides identity" idea. They are hackish work arounds - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287497/keycloak-role-based-client-log-in-access-restriction-for-users