# How can I restrict access to my Gitlab instance to certain OIDC SSO groups created with Keycloak?

Tags: permissions, gitlab, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Gitlab instance where we can connect in SSO with Keycloak in OIDC (omniAuth). Which works perfectly.

I have a keyclaok instance accessible via a url that allows me to manage groups, users...

I would like to restrict the access of my GitLab instance to some present groups in my Keycloak how can I do that ?

I have already tried to create roles by assigning them to groups, I have also tried to add policies to my client by adding groups that should have no access but it does not restrict access.

I tried to follow the exchanges on the following pages:

- [Keycloak: Role based client log-in access restriction for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287497/keycloak-role-based-client-log-in-access-restriction-for-users?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I restrict client access to only one group of users in keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305880/how-can-i-restrict-client-access-to-only-one-group-of-users-in-keycloak)

But following what it says, I don't have the desired result.

If someone has an idea, thanks in advance.

Here is my configuration for my client:

[image: gitlab-client]
[image: gitlab-client]